# Different lineHeight on Android / iOS using React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, fonts

Using a simple `<Text>` view with `lineHeight: 21` the same element seems to be rendered differently on Android and iOS devices. This is extremely annoying.

I have tested this both with "Arial" as default font, and with a custom font. Using a custom font (Sofia Pro Light), the differences become even larger.

What can I do to achieve the same fontStyling on both OS?

`fontFamily: Arial:` (Android 59dp, iOS 65pd)

[image: Arial]

`fontFamily: SofiaProLight` (Android 51.7dp, iOS 66pd)

[image: Sofia Pro]

Answer (score 0):

You need to give line height conditionally like follow

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

lineHeight: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 19 : 21
```